# Как правильно подключить файл с Namespace в PHP

Tags: php

Не совсем разобрался с namespace в php.
Допустим, есть два файла:

```
// File1
<?

namespace Db;
class Db {

}
?>

// File2
<?
namespace Data;
class Data {
}
?>
```

Если я хочу создать объект `Db` в классе `Data`, какие namespace я должен указать? Проинклудит ли php автоматически класс Db?

В файле `File2` я указал:

```
use Db;
```

Что выдало мне ошибку: `Class 'Db' not found`

Comment: use \Db\Db;

Comment: В папке такие файлы с классами: `user.php db.php index.php` В `index.php` я указал только: `use \Db\Db;  $obj = new User();` Получил ошибку: `Class 'User\User' not found`

Comment: файлы нужно инклудить. автоматически они не инклудятся

Comment: > файлы нужно инклудить. автоматически они не инклудятся

@Vasile, [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) вам в помощь, в котором реализован стандарт [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ru/)

Comment: @romeo, зачем советовать менеджер зависимостей, если нужен просто автозагрузчик?

Comment: @Etki: Каждый разработчик должен рано или поздно к этому прийти.

Comment: @romeo давайте сишку в каждый ответ ставить, к ней тоже нужно прийти.

Comment: @Etki, убедили.

Comment: @Vasile, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Иерархия:**

```
foo
 |-Foo.php
bar
 |-Bar.php    
-index.php
```

**Foo.php**

```
namespace foo;

class Foo 
{
    public function className()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

**Bar.php**

```
namespace bar;

class Bar 
{
    public function className()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $base_dir = __DIR__;
    $file = $base_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . '.php';
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        throw new \Exception("File is not found: {$file}");
    }
    require $file;
});

$foo = new \foo\Foo;
$bar = new \bar\Bar;

echo $foo->className(); // display: "foo\Foo" 
echo $bar->className(); // display: "bar\Bar"
```