# Как проверить существование класса?

Tags: php, mvc, autoload

Есть структура mvc и для удобства используется:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        get_include_path(),
        './some_dir',
    )));
spl_autoload_register(function($name) {
    require_once $name . '.php';
});
```

Пользователь делает запрос и нужно подключить класс контроллера:

```
function getController($request_name) {
     // операции с именем
     return new $request_name;
}
```

При отсутствии контролера получаю ошибки.

Пытаюсь проверить через `class_exists` - функция почему-то не работает.

`try`...`catch` - не работает.

Ошибки формата: сначала warning, что файла нет. Потом оно попадает в autoload и там уже fatal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверка класса не вызывая autoload:

```
var_dump(class_exists('BarController', false)); // false, если класс не найден
```

### Update

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    get_include_path(),
    __DIR__ . '/some_dir',
)));

spl_autoload_register(function($name) {
    $filename = $name . '.php';
    if (stream_resolve_include_path($filename) === false) {
        return;
    }
    require_once $filename;
});

var_dump(class_exists('BarController')); // false, если класс не найден
```

Если у вас версия PHP >= 5.3, то используйте пространство имен (namespace), тогда Ваш автозагрузчик будет [выглядеть вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/404903/10551).

**На будущее:** используйте [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Этот менеджер пакетов является де-факто стандартом для PHP. Примеров по настройке на том же github сколько угодно.

Comment: Таким образом автор никогда не найдет нужный класс, там в автозагрузчике проблема, а не в вызове.

Comment: @Etki Почему же. Если тот находиться в директории `./some_dir`, то найдёт. Естественно имя файла должно совпадать с именем класса. В остальном же, я с Вами согласен (вашим ответом): проверка на существование файла и т.д.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно, как добавляется папка `./some_dir`.

Comment: @romeo переписал через __ DIR __ - проблема осталась.

Comment: Был неправ про `include_path`.

Comment: @cisido Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

> Пытаюсь проверить через class_exists - функция почему-то не работает.

У `class_exists` есть дурацкое свойство пробовать автозагружать класс, если второй аргумент выставлен в `true` (это значение по умолчанию). Функция проверяет не наличие класса в текущем рантайме, а наличие класса в приложении - доступен ли он, если сейчас будет создан новый инстанс с помощью `new`. В момент *подзагрузки* PHP обратится к вашему автозагрузчику, который ***однозначно*** попытается загрузить файл, причем не `include_once`, после которого еще можно спасти ситуацию, а `require_once`, и делаете вы это даже без проверки на существование файла. Поэтому у вас потенциально убийственная ситуация что с `new`, что с `class_exists`.

**Что делать?**

В первую очередь автозагрузчик никогда не должен делать потенциально разрушительных действий. *Их может быть много*, система автозагрузчиков PHP устроена так, чтобы могло прийти двенадцать людей, установить по загрузчику, и все они отработали - если один не справился, в ход идет следующий. Поэтому ваш автозагрузчик должен просто *ничего не делать*, если он не может найти класс.

Второе, о чем стоит сказать, так это о менеджере зависимостей [Composer](https://getcomposer.org). Мне безумно не нравится, что он объединяет в себе функуции менеджера зависимостей и автозагрузчика, но в данный момент он является стандартом индустрии, поэтому проще всего было бы возложить автозагрузку на него.

Если же вы все-таки хотите написать свой собственный загрузчик - вам нужно сделать в нем проверку существования файла и регистрацию директории, относительно которой отсчитывать. Еще лучше это сделать согласно стандарту [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ru/), по которому работает автозагрузчик Composer. Насколько понимаю, первое предупреждение у вас из-за того, что вы указываете `include_path` от балды, и PHP сначала ищет класс там.

В любом случае после реализации корректного загрузчика вы сможете беспроблемно использовать `class_exists` для проверки существования класса.

Comment: в set_include_path перечень путей к папкам классам контроллерам, моделей и т.д.  Как я могу переписать автозакрузку, без Composer, чтобы работал class_exists?

Comment: @cisido, у вас там одна папка, которая плюсуется к тому, что уже в `include_path` есть (и еще DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, который в состоянии выдать конструкцию `/./some_dir`). Как сделать - я написал уже выше: делайте `require_once` после того, как убедились в существовании файла с помощью `file_exists`. Однако я не понимаю боязни использовать Composer.

Comment: переписал http://pastebin.com/TTrHgzpn. Теперь ничего не работает.

Comment: @cisido у вас автозагрузчик ищет файл внутри текущей папки. `include_path` и пользовательский автозагрузчик никак не пересекаются, и эта папка должна указываться внутри загрузчика. И все же я предложу либо написать полноценный загрузчик, либо предоставить эту задачу Composer.

Comment: Да `file_exists` ищет файл в текущей папке. Решил использовать функцию `stream_resolve_include_path`

Comment: Круто! Поднимаем планку ответов по тегу [php]!

Comment: @VladD ну я примерно такими ответами свою репу и наработал.